# Switch Case in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-1.3

I'm trying to put different template for different category based on category ID. I'm using Django 1.3. Switch case is not working with Django 1.3, I get this error:

```
Invalid block tag: 'switch', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock content'
```

but switch case had been correctly closed.

Here is my code:

```
{% switch property.category.id %}
        {% case 0 %}
                 <h4>'agriculture'</h4>
        {% case 1 %}
                  <h4>'Residential'</h4>
        {% case 2 %}
                  <h4>'commiercial'</h4>
        {% case 3 %}
                  <h4>'mixed use'</h4>
        {% case 4 %}
                  <h4>'Industrial'</h4>
        {% else %}
                 <h4>'retail'</h4>
{% endswitch %}
```

What is the error in this code?

Comment: Why would you think this would work? What makes you think there is a `switch` tag in Django? (And why are you using Django 1.3, which has been unsupported for years?)

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/967/  existing app was in 1.3 many years ago....Don't have permission to upgrade it.

Comment: So, have you put that code somewhere? Have you loaded the tag in your template?

Comment: Yes, its just a piece of code which i need to upgrade.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Where is the code in your project? Where is the line where you load that tag in your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `{% switch %}` tag in [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/). To solve your problem you can

- either use [this Django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/967/), that adds the functionality,
- or re-write your code to a series of `{% if %}`s.

The second option in code:

```
{% if property.category.id == 0 %}
    <h4>'agriculture'</h4>
{% elif property.category.id == 1 %}
    <h4>'Residential'</h4>
{% elif property.category.id == 2 %}
    <h4>'commiercial'</h4>
{% elif property.category.id == 3 %}
    <h4>'mixed use'</h4>
{% elif property.category.id == 4 %}
    <h4>'Industrial'</h4>
{% else %}
    <h4>'retail'</h4>
{% endif %}
```

As Alasdair correctly mentioned in his comment, the `{% elif %}` tag was [introduced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#minor-features) in Django 1.4. To use the above code in an older version you need to upgrade your Django version or you can use a modified version:

```
{% if property.category.id == 0 %}
    <h4>'agriculture'</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if property.category.id == 1 %}
    <h4>'Residential'</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if property.category.id == 2 %}
    <h4>'commiercial'</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if property.category.id == 3 %}
    <h4>'mixed use'</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if property.category.id == 4 %}
    <h4>'Industrial'</h4>
{% endif %}
{% if property.category.id < 0 or property.category.id > 4 %}
    <h4>'retail'</h4>
{% endif %}
```

This modification is safe** (but inefficient) here since the ID can't be equal to two different integers at the same time.

** as long as you only use integers for the IDs which is probable

**However** I would strongly recommend upgrading to a newer Django version. Not only because of the missing `{% elif %}` tag but mainly for security reasons.

Comment: elif was introduced in Django 1.4, the op is using Django 1.3.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks, you're right. I improved the answer.